# regex - specifying high Unicode codepoints in Python

Tags: regex, python-unicode

In Python 3.3 I have no trouble using ranges of Unicode codepoints within regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> to_delete = '[\u0020-\u0090\ufb00-\uffff]'
>>> s = 'abcdABCD¯˘¸ðﺉ﹅ﬄ你我他'
>>> print(s)
abcdABCD¯˘¸ðﺉ﹅ﬄ你我他
>>> print(re.sub(to_delete, '', s))
¯˘¸ð你我他
```

It's clean and simple. But if I include codepoints of five hex digits, that is to say anything higher than `\uffff`, such as `\u1047f`, as part of a range beginning in four hex digits, I get an error:

```
>>> to_delete = '[\u0020-\u0090\ufb00-\u1047f]'
>>> print(re.sub(to_delete, '', s))
...
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

There is no error if I start a new five-digit range, but I also do not get the expected behavior:

```
>>> to_delete = '[\u0020-\u0090\ufb00-\uffff\u10000-\u1047f]'
>>> print(re.sub(to_delete, '', s))
你我他
```

(The symbols  are codepoints `\u10000`, `\u10308`, and `\u10192`, respectively and should have been replaced in the last `re.sub` operation.)

---

Following the instructions of the accepted answer:

```
>>> to_delete = '[\u0020-\u0090\ufb00-\uffff\U00010000-\U0001047F]'
>>> print(re.sub(to_delete, '', s))
¯˘¸ð你我他
```

Perfect. Uglesome in the extreme, but perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u` only supports 16-bit codepoints. You need to use the 32-bit version, `\U`. Note that it requires 8 digits, so you have to prepend a few 0s (e.g. `\U00010D2B`).

Source: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code